# Remove Item error from category page only

Tags: cart, exception

If I click *Remove Item* in the (RWD Theme) Minicart **on the product view page, home page, other CMS pages, and cart page**, I have no problem.

If I click *Remove Item* **on the category page**, I get an exception error:

```
Invalid form key

Trace:
#0 /var/www/sites/mbs/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(604): Mage::throwException('Invalid form ke...')
#1 /var/www/sites/mbs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->ajaxDeleteAction()
#2 /var/www/sites/mbs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('ajaxDelete')
#3 /var/www/sites/mbs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#4 /var/www/sites/mbs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#5 /var/www/sites/mbs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /var/www/sites/mbs/index.php(96): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}
```

It appears that the URL *does* have the form key present in the URL, but it is invalid for some reason.

Even if I copy the Remove URL from the product page and overwrite the category URL (with Inspect Element), it gives me the same error.

### What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with the settings for one of our add ons, MANAdev Layered Navigation.

In the backend configuration settings, **I simply changed the "JavaScript libraries for Store Frontend" from `Load if required, minified version` to `Do not load`** (because we have jQuery loading elsewhere).

> [ManaDev Blog Post regarding this issue (July 2014)](http://www.manadev.com/blog/using-manadev-magento-extensions-with-1-9-rwd-theme/)

Apparently there was conflict due to multiple jQuery versions? It works as expected now.